# How to remove text after '-'?

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing

I have a list of files (basically they are `.deb` packages). Let's say:

```
abc-de-1.2.3-1.deb
fgh-ij-4.5.6-2.deb
klm-no-7.8.9-3.deb
pqrs-10.11.12-4.deb
...
```

As you can see some of the file names have numbers after a `-` while others have some text after a `-` and then numbers after the next `-`.

Are there any ways to remove everything starting from the numbers including the `-`, i.e.,

```
abc-de
fgh-ij
klm-no
pqrs
...
```

I want to edit the list, not rename the files.

Comment: it seems you want to cut of *always* from the second `-` from  the right. Is that *always* the case?

Comment: @JacobVlijm - For the last filename its the first `-`.

Comment: No it isn't, second hyphen *from the right* :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm - Oh sorry! No that's not always the case

Comment: @JacobVlijm   See Zanna's answer. OP wants to delete everything starting from the first number, reading left to right.    It's basically  `"-".join([ i for i in  "abc-de-1.2.3-1.deb".split("-") if not re.match('[0-9]', i) ])` in pythonic terms

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy yeah, but I was hoping to get a cheap shot with rfind, simply splitting by the second hyphen from the right ;)

Comment: @JacobVlijm nah, `rfind` won't do it.  `rfind` only works with substrings, not regex patterns

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy True, but in the examples it would work nicely, and very short.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Well, post it, let's see how it goes. I'll add another example  with `re`

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy unfortunately, OP mentioned it is not always the case :(

Comment: @JacobVlijm posted. Let me know what you think

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're able to use the first number to identify what you want to remove every time, you could use:

```
$ sed 's/-[0-9].*//' file
abc-de
fgh-ij
klm-no
pqrs
```

#### Notes

- `s/old/new/` replace `old` with `new`
- `[0-9]` some digit
- `.*` any number of any characters

Comment: Will it work if the list of filenames are in a text file?

Comment: @Raphael do you want to edit the list itself, or the names of only the files in the list? If the latter, where are the files? Are they in a directory with other things that you don't want to rename and that can't be distinguished from them using shell wildcards, or in multiple directories?

Comment: I have the filenames in a `txt` file and I want to edit the names in that file, i.e., I want to edit the list.

Comment: @Raphael OK, I don't understand what exactly you want to alter. The actual files or only the list that you have ?  Do you want the command to read the list and rename debs, or do you want command to only edit your list and not touch real debs ?

Comment: @Zanna - Edit only the list and not the actual files

Comment: @Raphael ok, fixed it (that was my original answer haha)

Comment: @Raphael you can use the same regex on rename utility if the files are actually exists `rename 's/-[0-9].*//' *.deb`

Answer (score 6):

Using `grep` with Perl regular expressions:

```
$ grep -Po "^[a-z-]*(?=-[0-9])" filename
abc-de
fgh-ij
klm-no
pqrs
```

Comment: Nice, very nice.

Answer (score 4):

#### Perl

```
$ perl -lne 's/([[:digit:]].*)//;s/-$//;print' input.txt                                                            
abc-de
fgh-ij
klm-no
pqrs
```

This performs two substitutions, one to delete everything that starts with a digit, and removes trailing `-`. Use `-i` options additionally to edit original file, like `$ perl -i -lne 's/([[:digit:]].*)//;s/-$//;print' input.txt`

Alternatively, with greedy non-digit match and grouping:

```
$ perl -lne 's/^(\D*)-.*/\1/;print' input.txt                                                                                                        
abc-de
fgh-ij
klm-no
pqrs
```

#### AWK

```
$ awk -F '-' '{s=$1;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/[0-9].*/){print s;next}else{s=s"-"$i}}' input.txt 
abc-de
fgh-ij
klm-no
pqrs
```

The way this works is that we treat `-` as separator for fields, then iterate over each line. We "cache" the first field, and move on iterating using `for` loop. On each iteration we check if the column doesn't contain a number we pad it to `s` variable. If the column contains a number - we print what we saved up and move on to next line.

Use `> new_file.txt` at the end to redirect output to new file.

#### Python

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys,re

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        tokens = re.split("-|\.",line.strip().replace(".deb",""))
        words_only = filter(lambda x: not x.isdigit(),tokens)
        print("-".join(words_only))
```

Using `re.split()` we break down every line into list of tokens, and filter only non-digit tokens.

Alternatively, here's a one-liner command. This doesn't take pre-caution of in case there's no digit in line, so only use this if you're sure all lines contain numbers.

```
$ python -c 'import re,sys;f=open(sys.argv[1]);print("\n".join([ l[:re.search(r"\d",l).start()-1] for l in f]))' input.txt
```

#### Potential numbers in package names

hvd  properly noted in the comments that there may be integers in package names sometimes, which may present a difficulty with parsing the input file, while version names typically have dots in them. With that in mind, the commands can be altered somewhat to counter that:

```
$ perl -lne 's/\d*\..*//;s/-$//;print' input.txt

$ awk '{gsub(/[0-9]*\..*/,"");print substr($0,0,length($0)-1)};' input.txt                                                                           

$ python -c 'import re,sys;f=open(sys.argv[1]);print("\n".join([ l[:re.search(r"\d*\.",l).start()-1] for l in f]))' input.txt
```

Comment: Haha, nice, but the python version might be a bit verbose for the job :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm, well, i could turn it into one liner or use `re.match` but that's be repeating same thing as sed or perl answers

Comment: Your Perl answer assumes the first digit will immediately follow a `-` symbol, but the OP's input looks like package names and versions, and it's not uncommon for package names to include digits as well.

Comment: @hvd   good point , however that probably should be commented towards OP, not my answer (or other answers, for that matter). They asked `remove everything starting from the numbers including the -`, so I provided what they asked. If they do have other type of packages in the list, I can revise the answer, but OP has to explicitly say so

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy The question specifies "numbers after a `-`" in the sentence before the one you're referring to, so personally, I think the question is clear enough as it is.

Answer (score 4):

Through awk,

```
awk -F'-[0-9]' '{print $1}' file
```

In awk, we can also pass a regex as an argument to Field Separator `-F`. So this would split each row on the part where the regex matches.

Example:

```
$ echo 'abc-de-1.2.3-1.deb' | awk -F'-[0-9]' '{print $1}'
abc-de
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll make a guess, since you suggested the files are DEB packages, then, perhaps you wanted something like:

```
dpkg-query -f '${Package}\n' -W 'gnome*'
```

Where, instead of `gnome*`, you could substitute any pattern. I'm not sure what exactly the convention is for naming DEB archives, but if those are DEB archives, it's probably best to rely on `dpkg` to give you the package name.

And if those are DEB archive files (on your system), then you could use:

```
dpkg-deb --showformat='${Package}\n' -W some-file.deb
```